# Confused about a mathematical induction detail

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction

Suppose I wish to prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ge 5,$ the statement $\mathscr{P}(n): n^2<2^n$ is true.

*Proof:*

Proceeding by induction on $n$, we note that $\mathscr{P}(5):(5)^2=25<2^5=32 \implies \mathscr{P}(5) $ holds. Now we induct on $n$ and assume the statement $\mathscr{P}(n)$ holds for some $n=k>5$, that is, we assume $\mathscr{P}(k): k^2<2^{k}$ holds for some $k\in\mathbb{N}>5$. We have: \begin{align}
        k^2<2^k\\\
        2k^2<2^{k+1}\\\
(k^2)+k^2<2^{k+1}\\\
(2k+1)+k^2<(k^2)+k^2<2^{k+1}\\\
\end{align}

The last inequality $2k^2>k^2+2k+1$ follows from the fact that $k^2-2k-1=(k-1)^2-2>0$ for $k>5>1\pm\sqrt{2}.$ Continuing, we have that: \begin{align}
k^2+2k+1<2k^2<2^{k+1}\\\
(k+1)^2<2k^2<2^{k+1}\\\
\implies (k+1)^2<2^{k+1}\space\text{as desired}\space
\end{align}

Hence we have shown that the truth of $\mathscr{P}(k) \implies\space\text{the truth of}\space\mathscr{P}(k+1)\space\text{for any}\space k\in\mathbb{N}>5$. We have shown by the Principle of Mathematical Induction that $n^2<2^n$ for all $n\ge5$. $\square$

My concern with my proof is using the auxiliary notion that $k^2>2k+1$ in the induction step. Is this proof valid? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Having to use some "extra fact" to prove something is typical, even as an intermediate step in a larger proof. So yes this is fine. You could get away with being more terse: you want to get $(k+1)^2<2^{k+1}$ and $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$ so it suffices to have $P(k)$ (assumed) and $2k+1<2^k$ (which you must show some other way).

Comment: Unless you are trying to avoid the use of some known or provable fact, just use it if you want..... BTW  a Q on this site asked to prove $(n^2+n)/2=\sum_{j=1}^nj$ for all $n\in \Bbb N, $  $without$ induction. Many answers, all rejected by the proposer for using induction (implicitly or explicitly).  The problem is that you cannot even define what $\exists n\,(x= \sum_{j=1}^n j) $ means, from the basic axioms of arithmetic, without induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly valid, nowhere does it say that you need to use only the inductive hypothesis and nothing else. You even proved the 'auxiliary notion' to boot.